# I'm not getting data in $scope.Attendancesdata

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-mvc

I can pass the data from Home/GetAllAttendanceData but in controller $scope.Attendancesdata cant access that data.my module,service and controller code is shown below.

```
## Home/GetAllAttendanceData ##
public JsonResult GetAllAttendanceData()
    {
         var bookList = db.Attendances.Where(x => x.Id == 1).ToList(); 
        return Json(bookList, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);     
    }

 ## service.js ##
 app.service("crudAJService", function ($http) {
  this.getdata = function () {
    return $http.get("Home/GetAllAttendanceData");
};
});




## Module.js ##
var app = angular.module("myModule", []);



## Controller.js ##
app.controller("myController", function ($scope, crudAJService) {
debugger;
$scope.divBook = false;
GetAlldata();
function GetAlldata() {
    debugger;
    var getAttendanceData = crudAJService.getdata();
    getAttendanceData.then(function(Attendances) {
        $scope.Attendancesdata = Attendances.data;
    }, function () {
        alert('Error in getting book records');
    });
}
});
```

Comment: Do you get the expected data when you go tovHome/GetAllAttendanceData directly in your browser?

Comment: how to check whether data is present in browser?? it is successfully returning the data from  Home/GetAllAttendanceData.

Comment: I am very new to this...sorry to ask some simple questions

Comment: and thanks in advance..

Comment: Just go to that url.  Depending on your configuration, either you will see json in the browser or it'll prompt you to download it.  Having dev tools open in your browser will help as well.  From it you can see network activity and console for errors.

Comment: it shows this in console

Comment: A circular reference was detected while serializing an object of type 'System.Data.Entity.DynamicProxies.Attendance_8F407FBB98394957728F55B0817F48FF2CC1A1F6B96B29AA1B2FE268A097B593'.

Comment: Are you trying to serialize an object retrieved from Entity Framework which references other objects? (For example Attendences & AttendenceDays)?

Comment: I tried this code and that error is gone now..

Comment: return this.Json(
           (from obj in db.Attendances select new { Id = obj.Id, EmpNTLogin = obj.EmpNTLogin }),
           JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet
           );